AngularFire: get the isNewUser flag;
I need to get hold of the 'additionalUserInfo.isNewUser'.
  import { User, getAdditionalUserInfo, getAuth, user, UserCredential } from '@angular/fire/auth';

  afAuth = getAuth();

  user$: Observable<User | null> = user(this.afAuth);

  userSubscription = this.user$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(firebaseUser => {

        if (!firebaseUser) return of(null);

        return from(firebaseUser.getIdTokenResult())
          .pipe(
            map(idTokenResult => {
              // ... map claims from token to user object;
              return userWithClaims;
            }),
           
            //TODO: I need the 'additionalUserInfo.isNewUser' here
          );
      }),
      ...

AngularFire provides the 'UserCredential' interface and the 'getAdditionalUserInfo' method,

but I don't know where to get the 'userCredential' object from.
getAdditionalUserInfo(userCredential: UserCredential) { ... }

I wasn't able to find anything helpful in the "Convenience observables" section.
To clarify my question - I'm aware of the fact that the 'signIn...' methods return the 'UserCredential' object.
  onSignInWithGoogleButtonClicked(): void {
    
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    
    const auth = getAuth();
    
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((userCredential) => {

The question is, how do I get this object into the 'user$' stream. Isn't there a nice '@angularfire way' of achieving this? Do I need to resort to combining these in an RxJS fashion?

This question is similar to: Check for isNewUser with Firebase email link auth using modular JS SDK. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hey @SangwinGawande - I beg to differ. It might seem similar, but I'm using the '@angular/fire' package. I updated my question - the tricky part is getting the credentials into the $user stream.

I think you need to sign in with the User first, To get the UserCredential data.
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })

Then you can use the getAdditionalUserInfo method separately
import {getAdditionalUserInfo} from "firebase/auth"

const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(userCredential)

If firebaseUser is your userCredential then the code would become link this :
import { User, getAdditionalUserInfo, getAuth, user, UserCredential } from '@angular/fire/auth';

afAuth = getAuth();

user$: Observable<User | null> = user(this.afAuth);

userSubscription = this.user$
.pipe(
  switchMap(firebaseUser => {

    if (!firebaseUser) return of(null);

    return from(firebaseUser.getIdTokenResult())
      .pipe(
        map(idTokenResult => {
          // ... map claims from token to user object;
          return userWithClaims;
        }),
       
        //TODO: I need the 'additionalUserInfo.isNewUser' here

          const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(firebaseUser);
          return isNewUser;
      );
  }),
  ...


Hello @SangwinGawande you need a 'userCredential: UserCredential' object to pass it into the 'getAdditionalUserInfo' method. If you pass the 'firebaseUser: Firebase.User' into the method, it will not  even compile.

Use signInWithEmailAndPassword and get userCredential context then...
